# I have an issue fetching data after filtering

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I am working on a table with React and MUI and I'm trying to resolve a bug.

The thing is that when I type in the text field and press enter, the information is filtered properly.

but I have a button that clears the filters from the text fields, so when I click on the button it clears the filter and fetch the data but with the filter(s) and I have to click on the button again to bring all the information back without filtering

```
const handleClearFilters = () => {
    setFiltros((prevFilters) => ({
      ...prevFilters,
      plazas: "",
      puesto: "",
      estatus: "",
      nombre: "",
    }));

    // Now, fetchData will be called after the state has been updated
    fetchData(0, {
      plazas: "",
      puesto: "",
      estatus: "",
      nombre: "",
    });
  };
  const handleOnKeyUp = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") fetchData();
  };
```

So I know that it's possible that the state is not updated synchronously, I already tried using setTimeout and but I'm having the same issue.

I need that the filters get clear and then fetch the whole data again. can someone help me with this?